# JavaScript Sort Function

Tags: javascript, function, sorting

I am trying to get my js to list my names VERTICALLY in my form box but it only comes in HORIZONTALLY, do you know why? Thanks.
This is my script:

```
// initialize the counter and the array
var numnames=0;
var names = new Array();

function SortNames() {
    // Get the name from the text field
    thename=document.theform.newname.value;
    // Add the name to the array
    names[numnames]=thename;
    // Increment the counter
    numnames++;
    // Sort the array
    names.sort();
    document.theform.sorted.value=names.join("\n");
}
```

Comment: What is `document.theform.sorted`? A `textarea`?

Answer (score 2):

That code has a couple of issues, but provided the form fields really exist, that the names you're referencing are the names of the fields, and that `sorted` is a `textarea`, it should essentially work: [Example](http://jsbin.com/acibig). So my guess is that `sorted` is an `input type="text"` instead. Change it to a `textarea`.

---

**Off-topic** (slightly): FWIW, the issues I alluded to:

1. You're not declaring your `thename` variable, and so falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).
2. Your `numnames` variable is unnecessary (and a maintenance issue); just use `names.length`.
3. The convention in JavaScript (which you're free to ignore) is that you use an initial capital letter in functions only when they're *constructor* functions (functions you call via `new`), and that you use lower case for all other functions. So `sortNames` rather than `SortNames`, or better yet, `addNameToList` or similar since it *doesn't* just sort the names.

Also, recommend `var names = [];` over `var names = new Array();`, but they both work.

Comment: names.length as in names[names.length]=thename;

Comment: @pimvdb: Either way, the point is that `names.length` serves the purpose `numnames` appears to be trying to serve (not just when adding, but later if you want to know how many there are). (Side note: The assignment idiom [is faster than `push`](http://jsperf.com/silly-test-of-ways-to-append-to-arrays) on nearly all browsers, but you'd have to be in one heck of a tight loop to care and I use `push` for clarity.)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: You're correct (though in Chrome the `push` turns out to be faster).

Comment: 'sorted" is also embedded in my HTML file: <textarea cols="60" rows="10" name"sorted">. Do you suggest that I change "sorted" in both javascript and HTML files? Right now if I type in names in the name field one name at the time and then enter the names go into the form box vertically, but if I input them in group with or without comma between them, they go into the form box horizontally only.

Comment: @Sigh: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand you. But if by *" if I input them in group with or without comma between them, they go into the form box horizontally only"* you mean literally that you're typing "name1,name2,name3" in the `newname` field, then of course those names will be treated as one name. You'd have to use `split` or something when retrieving them from the field to split them into individual entries on whatever delimiter(s) it is/are you want to use, and then add those individually to the sorted list.